# Loading a script via JS code doesn't execute it on certain page, but works on other pages

Tags: javascript, global-variables, umd

I am dynamically load a script, which when executed will expose a global prop on the `window` object.
However, on our shopping cart page it doesn't work - I see the network request, it is successful - but that's it. No errors in the console so far.

I tried two ways:

1. With jQuery's getScript method:

```
    $.getScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bowser@latest/es5.js');
```

2. With native JS:

```
    var bowserScript = document.createElement('script');
    bowserScript.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bowser@latest/es5.js';
    document.body.appendChild(bowserScript);
```

And later, when user do something, under some condition I'm using `window.bowser` - which comes from this script.

This works on all pages except the shopping cart page. It is a single page app. It loads some React components, even though the SPA is not built with React.

So - any idea where the problem could come from? Some setting of the page, some meta tag ...? ... I've tried on other places, also tried to prepare fiddler - but it simply works everywhere else.

Comment: Check F12 developer tools, both console and network tabs. Console will show errors. Network will allow you to see resources that don't load (along with a code).

Comment: @devlincarnate - I checked and I see successful network request (200) and no errors - on all pages. Just the code doesn't look to be executed on the shopping cart page.